# How to change a view overriding the query using views_pre_execute?

Tags: views

I want to change a view overriding his query using views_pre_execute.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) { 

global $user;

$userid = $user->uid;

if($view->name=="order_selection") {
$custom_query = db_select('commerce_order','fco');
$custom_query->join('field_data_field_restid','ffdfr', 'fco.order_id = ffdfr.entity_id');
$custom_query->join('field_data_field_username','ffdfu', 'ffdfr.field_restid_value = ffdfu.entity_id');
$custom_query->join('users','fu', 'ffdfu.field_username_target_id = fu.uid');
    $custom_query->fields('fco' , array('order_id', 'order_number', 'mail', 'created', 'status'));
$custom_query->fields('fu' , array('name'));
$custom_query->condition('fu.uid', $userid , '=');

$view->build_info['query'] = $custom_query;;

$result = $custom_query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('order_id');

$header = array();
$header[] = array(
    array('data'=>'Nr. comanda', 'field'=>'order_number'),
    array('data'=>'E-mail','field'=>'mail'),
    array('data'=>'Data comenzii','field'=>'created'),
    array('data'=>'Status', 'field'=>'status'));

$data = array();
foreach($result as $record){ 
    $data[] = array(
        array('data'=>$record->order_number),
        array('data'=>$record->mail),
        array('data'=>$record->created),
            array('data'=>$record->status));    
//$data[] = array($record->mail);
}

$html = theme('table',
    array('header'=>$header,
    'rows'=>$data,
    'attributes'=>array(), 
    'caption'=>'',
    'sticky' => TRUE,
    'empty' => 'No rows',
    'colgroups'=>array()));
$html .= theme('pager',
    array(
        'tags'=>array()
    )
);
print render($html);
} }
```

I can see the correct results but these are displayed without a header and in a wrong place at the top of the page.
The major problem is that the table of the original (unwanted) view is still displayed in the main content area of the page. How can I completely remove the original view and replace it in the main content with the one generated by views_pre_execute?
Also can someone give me a hint why the header is not displayed?

Comment: What is the goal/purpose for the query override?

Comment: I need to make a complex query to select all the orders made for a certain user (seller) by other users (buyers). I cannot figure out how to do it using the Views interface. For me is much simpler to write SQL code and than to use views_pre_execute.Thats why I kept in the Views interface a very simple query selecting all the order_id's and in view_pre_execute I used a complex query that I need. I can show the results with print but I dont know how to display these in a proper way and that means in place of the old view results table.